friend operator << and >> in base class without child class but still called
Why is the operators << and >> called in base class if they are defined as 'friend' when calling << and >> in child class?
Code:
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Baza
{
protected:
    int n;
public:
    Baza() { cout << "B\n"; }
    virtual ~Baza() { cout << "~B\n"; }

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Baza& b);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Baza& b);
};

istream& operator>>(istream& in, Baza& b)
{
    cout<<"op >>"<<endl;
    return in;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Baza& b)
{
    cout<<"op<<"<<endl;
    return out;
}

class Derivata : public Baza
{
public:
    Derivata() { cout << "D\n"; }
    ~Derivata() { cout << "~D\n"; }


};



int main()
{
    vector<Derivata> v;
    v.push_back(new Derivata);

// works
    Derivata d;
    cin>>d;
    cout<<d;

    return 0;
}

Is c++ compiler creating a operators that calls the base class method's operator by default when compiling?
Rephrase: in base class (which is baza) are defined operators << and >> as friend. Derivata class inherits the 'baza' (base class), but operators are not inherited because they're friends. why are they called if i use >> and << in 'derivata' class?

Er, the derived class inherits base class stuff, like operators. This is expected behavior.

It has nothing to do with friend. Derivata is Baza and the operators with Baza&  are chosen successfully.

sorry, i modified.

Simpler example showing the same phenomenon: `void foo(const Baza&) {}
int main() {
Derivata d;
foo(d);
}` Would you expect this version to not work?

operators >> and << are defined as friends methods thus they're not inherited.

oh dammed. in base class (which is baza) are defined operators << and >> as friend. Derivata class inherits the 'baza' (base class), but operators are not inherited because they're friends. why are they called if i use >> and << in 'derivata' class?

You can remove friend ... and ensure friend is not a subject of your question.

@273k is that a joke?

@sticknycu Nothing is being inherited.  This is just normal overload resolution.  friend functions aren't part of the class, even if they're defined within the class definition.  They're just normal freestanding functions.

I don't joke. You are excessively focused on friend.

Well, the question is how are they called then if they are not defined in 'Derivata' class and why is called operators of base class?

How they are called is shown in the fourth comment. They ARE NOT operators of base class.

Compiler creates a constructor of 'derivata' which calls the 'base' class (basically an instantion of 'baza' class and that calls methods << and >> ?

The operator>> and operator<< you've defined are in no way part of the Baza class.  The friend keyword doesn't do that; it just gives them permission to access Baza's private and protected members.
In that way, what you have is no different from this:
class Baza {};
class Derivata : public Baza {};

void some_function(Baza&) {}

int main() {
    Derivata d;
    some_function(d);
}

A reference to a base class can be bound to an object of a class derived from that base class, so a Baza& can be bound to a Derivata object.  That allows you to pass objects of the derived class to functions that accept references to the base class.
Replacing some_function with an overloaded operator doesn't change anything about the semantics of how it's looked up or what objects can be passed to it.  All it changes is the syntax used to call it.
